# Color Matrix to sharpjs/ image processing lib

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, image-processing, sharp

Hello I was wondering if anyone knew how to apply filters on an image using sharpjs(preferably) or any image processing lib with a nodejs SDK using only a colorMatrix. The two inputs I have are the input image and the 4 x 5 color matrix and I want to transform the input image using the color matrix. For context, I can do transformations in the web browser canvas API using feColorMatrix tag but I want to actually manipulate the image on the backend now. Has anyone got any experience with this?

Comment: what like: https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/api-operation#recomb

Comment: @LawrenceCherone thanks for replying, i already looked that that but then that allows just a 2x2 and 3x3 matrix, this is a 4x5 matrix. have you previously made this time of transformation with sharp js ?